# Does cluster reject queries when rolling restart?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is the post of rolling restarts:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_rolling_restarts.html

Does it affect any queries running during this process? The process does not explicitly let clusters know a node will be killed, but only stop sync and rebalancing. Are existing queries rejected or retried?

There is another option
"transient": {
"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip":
}
which can 'disable' a node to restart and rebalance data. Is this one better than the approach the link says?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your cluster configuration. You can avoid it.

If you have replicas and not querying restarting node directly you should be fine.

First of all, take a look at [coordinating node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node) note

> Requests like search requests or bulk-indexing
>   requests may involve data held on different data nodes. A search
>   request, for example, is executed in two phases which are coordinated
>   by the node which receives the client request — the coordinating node.
>
> In the scatter phase, the coordinating node forwards the request to
>   the data nodes which hold the data. Each data node executes the
>   request locally and returns its results to the coordinating node. In
>   the gather phase, the coordinating node reduces each data node’s
>   results into a single global resultset.
>
> Every node is implicitly a coordinating node. This means that a node
>   that has all three node.master, node.data and node.ingest set to false
>   will only act as a coordinating node, which cannot be disabled. As a
>   result, such a node needs to have enough memory and CPU in order to
>   deal with the gather phase.

There could be different edge cases:

1. you have only one node in cluster: requests will fail -- add more nodes
2. you have several nodes in cluster and 0 replicas for your shards: if you need data from restarting node in your query, request will partially fail -- have replicas
3. you have several nodes with replicas and you querying restarting node directly: request will fail -- exclude restarting nodes from your application or always query dedicated coordinating node, it will take care about nodes leaving the cluster.